# bootstrap doctype with input form-control width is not show correctly

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem with bootstrap 3.3.5

I created a simple web page to test a new bootstrap. This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="id">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>BS Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

        <form class="form">
            <div class="form-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The input text with class `form-control` width more than browser width so the scrollbar at the bottom show..

and when the `<!DOCTYPE html>` remove, all very normal width.

how I can solve this problem with `<!DOCTYPE html>`?

with doctype:
[image]

and this without doctype:
[image]

please help, thank you

Comment: You have a `.row` without any `.col-*`, which is wrong. See https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E013

Comment: All modern web pages are required to have a doctype. Without one, you are in "quirks mode". You should never be in quirks and should not be concerned with how one looks without a doctype.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<div class="container">
```

instead of

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

Comment: An explanation would be helpful. What was the problem and how does your solution solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in `<!DOCTYPE html>`. The issue is due to the missing of **col-***.
Try the below code

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <form class="form">
        <div class="form-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```